# Get neighbours of each two dimensional array element

Tags: php, node.js

I have two-dimensional array of elements like

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Now how do I get neighbours of each element?

For Ex : For 1 neighbours are [2,4] and for 2[1,3,5] etc.

Do suggest how can I do this.

Expected Output :

```
[
1=>[2,4],
2=>[1,3,5],
3=>[2,6],
4=>[1,5,7],
5=>[2,4,6,8],
6=>[3,5,9],
7=>[4,8],
8=>[7,5,9],
9=>[6,8]
]
```

Comment: Do you want a PHP or a JS answer?  Where is the work you've done so far?

Comment: any language fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @jmargolisvt please find expected output

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple, functional way of finding neighbors concisely. It defines neighbors with a vector so you could use it to filer other ways too:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]


function neighbors(arr, m, n) {
  // define what a neighbor is
  let v = [[0, 1],[1, 0],[0, -1],[-1, 0]]
  // filter edges & map
  return v.filter(([h, j]) => h + m >= 0 && h + m < arr.length && j + n >= 0 && j + n < arr[0].length)
    .map(([h, j]) => arr[h + m][j + n])

}

console.log(neighbors(arr, 1, 1))
console.log(neighbors(arr, 0, 0))
console.log(neighbors(arr, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Js:

Suppose **array** with **rowSize** and **columnSize**

```
for(i=0;i<rowSize;i++){

    //neighbours of element array[i][j]

    for(j=0;j<columnSize;j++){
        if(i!=0)
          console.log(array[i-1][j]);

        if(i!=rowSize-1)
          console.log(array[i+1][j]);

        if(j!=0)
          console.log(array[i][j-1]);

        if(j!=columnSize-1)
          console.log(array[i][j+1]);
    }
}
```